# How can I read multiple CSV files and display specific results using PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I know basic PHP and SQL, and normally I would solve the following with a database.

I have several CSV files that all contain a common PERSON_ID. For this task I am unable to use any database, just the files in the same folder, and I want to display the data that corresponds to the ID using PHP and HTML.

Is there a way to get just the data that is associated to the ID from all files and then set values to work into a displayable HTML format?

For example, FILE-1.CSV looks like this:

```
PERSON_ID,THE_DATE,CODE,VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3,VALUE4
123,11/21/2013,ABC987,6,2,5,8
234,10/15/2011,DEF542,4,2,5,8
345,8/23/2012,GHI34,6,7,5,8
456,2/7/2012,FDA1,2,1,5,8
567,4/30/2011,QWERTY4,6,2,4,8
678,1/23/2014,ABC987,2,2,6,8
```

And FILE-2.CSV looks like this:

```
CASE_NUMBER,PERSON_ID,STATUS,STATE
98,456,Active,CA
97,678,Active,WA
96,123,Completed,NJ
95,567,Active,TX
94,456,Completed,OH
93,345,Active,UT
```

If I had the URL "my.php?person_id=456" can I get the PHP output to say:

```
PERSON_ID: 456 
Number of Cases: 2 
Date on system: 2/7/2012 
Cases: 98 (Active in CA), 94 (Completed in OH)
```

Thank you in advance, I hope this is achievable :)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This is fairly simple in that you just need to read 2 csv files looking for rows with a the person id and then collect the data for ouput.

Comment: Give it a shot. Basically you'll have 2 loops. The first one you loop through the first csv file looking for that person. Save that data and break out of the loop. Then loop the 2nd file and save any data where the person_id matches. After that it's as easy as displaying the data you have in your arrays.

Comment: I have tried using the fgetcsv, but the only examples out there I can find is to display the whole CSV file and not a specific entry? Can you point me to this example please?

Comment: With a csv you have to loop through it. Depending on what you want to do you don't have to loop through it all. In your case, the first one you loop till you find the person then break. In the second one you will loop through it all because the person can have more than one case. Update your post and add the code you've tried.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but I can't find an example that does this . Is there a specific term I need to search for? I feel you might be overestimating my knowledge of looping CSVs.

Answer (score 0):

You should add in some checks. For instance, if no id is passed in the url, then you shouldn't loop through any of the files. If the person isn't found don't loop the cases csv and display a message about not finding the person. Also if there are no cases for the person you should display a message saying no cases found.

```
$id = $_GET['person_id'];
$person = array();
$cases = array();
$case_str = '';

if (($handle = fopen("file-1.csv", "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $person_id = $data[0];
        $the_date = $data[1];
        $code = $data[2];
        $value1 = $data[3];
        $value2 = $data[4];
        $value3 = $data[5];
        $value4 = $data[6];

        if($person_id == $id) {
            $person = array('person_id' => $person_id, 'the_date' => $the_date, 'code' => $code, 'value1' => $value1, 'value2' => $value2, 'value3' => $value3, 'value4' => $value4);
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

if (($handle = fopen("file-2.csv", "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $case_number = $data[0];
        $person_id = $data[1];
        $status = $data[2];
        $state = $data[3];

        if($person_id == $id) {
            $cases[] = array('case_number' => $case_number, 'person_id' => $person_id, 'status' => $status, 'state' => $state);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

echo "PERSON_ID: " . $id . "<br />\n";
echo "Number of Cases: " . count($cases) . "<br />\n";
echo "Date on system: " . $person['the_date'] . "<br />\n"; 
echo "Cases: ";
foreach($cases as $case) {
    $case_str .= $case['case_number'] . " (" . $case['status'] . " in " . $case['state'] . "),";
}
echo rtrim($case_str, ',');
```

Comment: This is incredibly valuable to me, thank you for your time. I'll go over this and see how things turn out. Thank you SlapYo :)

Comment: No problem. It should get you pointed in the right direction. Any questions just comment and I'll jump back to help out.